# Date parsing troubles with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, d3.js

So I've been trying to get a jsfiddle example with d3.js working where it say takes in a string input such as;

```
"8/8/2011 12:00:00 AM"
```

And with that string can create a Date Object from parsing out the date info with regex.

I've been using near identical regex from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759434/i-am-trying-to-validate-a-date-with-a-regular-expression-in-javascript-but-it-is) one. The format I'm trying to capture is a simple MM/DD/YYYY with actual validation I'll do by passing it into a Date object later on.

The actual regex pattern I came up with to do small validation is:

```
(([01]?[0-2]|[0-9])(\/)([0-2]?[0-9]|3[01])(\/)((19|20)\d{2}))
```

However my pattern is giving me some issues it seems with flags and matching/validating. [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/EqduPp9ehC) validates fine without any flags and gets all the dates matched, but will break if I put the global flag (g) on the pattern. However with [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lK3jA6) I need to put the global flag (g) for it to be able to match all the dates I put for test strings. I'm confused if the flag truly matters or not and would love some clarification.

Next to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NEEe/9/) example which stopped giving me any alert or feedback. However I'm also having trouble getting RegEx.exec(str) to properly work like I want. I thought I had it pushing the first entry in the array, which would be the date string I wanted. However like I said I don't get any feedback or alerts pop-up that I have set. According to jsfiddle my javascript is valid, so I'm at a lost.

I have it all commented with the logic of what I was trying to do, but I've tried everything that I could think of and wouldn't mind someone else taking a small look and pointing out something I may have missed.

Comment: D3 provides functions to parse and format dates, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't using regex at all, but have you tried using the Date.parse() function in javascript?
In your case, you can do something like this:

```
var dateString = "8/10/2011 12:00:00 AM"; // used different month to date for highlighting purposes
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(Date.parse(dateString));

date.getFullYear(); // returns 2011;
date.getMonth() // returns 7 (months are 0-11)
date.getDate(); // returns 10
```

More info here: [MDN Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: Now I feel dumb for not knowing about this and struggling for hours. 

Thanks for the much easier alternative.

Comment: The documentation lists date formats ISO8601 and RFC2822, though it appears to work correctly, across browsers, using the date format above with slashes.